# Custom key class <string, bool> not present in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out how to use custom class as key in dictionary. My class

```
public class Enabler
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode() ^ Enabled.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Enabler);
    }

    public bool Equals(Enabler obj)
    {
        return obj != null && obj.Name == this.Name;
    }
}
```

And when I try to use it:

```
Dictionary<Enabler, List<AppSettingsElement>> appSettings = new Dictionary<Enabler, List<AppSettingsElement>>();
appSettings.Add(new Enabler {Name = "none", Enabled = true }, new List<AppSettingsElement>());
Enabler myKey = new Enabler { Name = "none" };
appSettings[myKey].Add(new AppSettingsElement { Comment = text, Name = name, Value = "value" });
//last line throws "myKey not found in dictionary" error.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `Equals` method should match `GetHashCode` - right now, `Enabled` is considered by only one of them. Note: mutable keys are a *terrible* idea

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't quite understand what int should I return there, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Kajbo see my posted answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods need to be compatible. Right now, your `GetHashCode` method considers `Enabled`, but `Equals` does not, which can lead to things being unfindable. Either remove the `Enabled` check from `GetHashCode`:

```
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
```

or add it to `Equals`:

```
    public bool Equals(Enabler obj)
    {
        return obj != null && obj.Name == this.Name
            && obj.Enabled == this.Enabled;
    }
```

noting that with the second option, `myKey` will need to have `Enabled = true` to be a match.

Note: mutable keys are a terrible terrible idea. You should consider:

```
public Enabler(string name, bool enabled)
{
    Name = name;
    Enabled = enabled;
}
public string Name { get; }
public bool Enabled { get; }
```

to make it immutable.

Note: if you make it immutable, it might also make sense for this to be a `struct`, so:

```
public struct Enabler
{ ... }
```

and fixing the `null` checks:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
    => Equals(obj is Enabler e && Equals(e));

public bool Equals(Enabler obj)
    => obj.Name == this.Name && obj.Enabled == this.Enabled;
```

Either way, you should also make `Enabler` implement `IEquatable<Enabler>`, i.e.

```
public class Enabler : IEquatable<Enabler>
```

or

```
public struct Enabler : IEquatable<Enabler>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'll also remake it into immutable.

Comment: Don't you need to check for null in `GetHashCode`?

Comment: @Evk on `Name`? yes, probably - but arguably it would be better to check that in the constructor, i.e. `Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));`